# Removing HTML elements with javascript when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have several clickable HTML elements that all use the same JS function when clicked.

Now when one of "floor" is clicked I want it to remove that "tile" div and "floor" div.

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="floor" onclick="killTile()"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div  class="floor" onclick="killTile()"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="floor" onclick="killTile()"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="floor" onclick="killTile()"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="floor" onclick="killTile()"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="floor" onclick="killTile()"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

killTile function:

```
function killTile(){
    // Play explosion sound effect
    xpld.pause();
    xpld.currentTime = 0;
    xpld.play();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the function a parameter:

```
function killTile(which) {
    // Play explosion sound effect
    xpld.pause();
    xpld.currentTime = 0;
    xpld.play();
    var tilediv = which.parentNode;
    tilediv.parentNode.removeChild(tilediv);
}
```

Then call it as:

```
<div class="floor" onclick="killTile(this)"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove a DOM node you can use [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) method:

```
function killTile(obj) {
    // Play explosion sound effect
    xpld.pause();
    xpld.currentTime = 0;
    xpld.play();

    // remove parent node
    obj.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(obj.parentNode);
}
```

and pass `obj` as:

```
<div class="tile">
    <div  class="floor" onclick="killTile(this)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this..

```
function killTile(obj){
    // Play explosion sound effect
    xpld.pause();
    xpld.currentTime = 0;
    xpld.play();

    obj.parentElement.remove();
}
```

Call it like onClick="KillTile(this)"

Comment: This just removes the floor, not the tile.

Comment: Oops, I thought you were using `removeChild`, like the other answers. The problem with `remove` is that it's new, and not as compatible as `removeChild`. If you edit your answer to include caveats, I'll be able to remove my downvote.